# mssql bulk insert not working while executing from php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

I have the following bulk insert script

```
$sql="BULK
                INSERT nibble
                FROM 'd:\nibble.csv'
                WITH
                (
                FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
                ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
                FIRSTROW=2
                )

                ";
mssql_query($sql);
```

**Msg 4860, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot bulk load. The file "d:ibble.csv" does not exist.**

but when i execute from sql below server management studio it works .. what is the issue

```
BULK
                INSERT nibble
                FROM 'd:\nibble.csv'
                WITH
                (
                FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
                ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
                FIRSTROW=2
                )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash with another backslash. From `d:\nibble.csv` to `d:\\nibble.csv`

Do this way..

```
<?php
$sql="BULK
                INSERT nibble
                FROM 'd:\\nibble.csv'
                WITH
                (
                FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
                ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
                FIRSTROW=2
                )

                ";
mssql_query($sql);
```